# Need to update table based on selected value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to update a table based on a queried value from another table the logic is as follows:
I need to select the column resid which will have numbers that represent servers:

```
Select [resid] from [dbo].[dailyChecksIntegrityErrorState2]
```

Then i need to say

```
if [resid] ='1077'
```

then

```
update [dbo].[DailyChecks] set prdintegritycheckbox ='0'
```

I know this is a newby question, I need some direction on how to formulate the if then/else statement

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work
    `Update [dbo].[DailyChecks] set prdintegritycheckbox ='0'
    where (Select [resid] from [dbo].[dailyChecksIntegrityErrorState2] where [resid]= '1077')`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want something like this:

```
update dc
    set prdintegritycheckbox = '0'
    from [dbo].[DailyChecks] dc
    where dc.server in (Select [resid] from [dbo].[dailyChecksIntegrityErrorState2] where resid = '1077')
```

or:

```
update dc
    set prdintegritycheckbox = '0'
    from [dbo].[DailyChecks] dc
    where dc.server in (Select [resid] from [dbo].[dailyChecksIntegrityErrorState2]) and
          dc.server = '1077'
```